# Keyboard shortcut script not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, scripts, brightness

I finally gave up on getting my <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>up/down</kbd> keys to change my screen brightness on my laptop. I took a `brightnessup.sh` and `brightnessdown.sh` script and put them in `/etc/acpi` and then went to keyboard shortcuts to and assigned the scripts to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>up</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>down</kbd> and finally after months was able to change my brightness with my keyboard. But no sooner did I get it working, I restarted my computer and it no longer works.

Can anybody tell me how to get this working again?

In terminal `sudo /etc/acpi/brightnessup.sh` and `sudo /etc/acpi/brightnessdown.sh` changes the brightness so I know the script works but it is not running with the assigned keys.

Comment: Do these scripts work without sudo?

Comment: I binded [this script](http://askubuntu.com/a/408361/21679) to brightness keys on my laptop with "Custom shortcuts" -- KDE control model (I binded `brightness.bash -i 10` and `brightness.bash -d 10`),